# Iterate Workspace not working in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, iterator, file-path, parse

I created a model in ArcGIS Pro that will delete features (ex. drainage areas) that intersect with unfeasible landcover classes within a raster (ex. impervious). So I used the following model structure: Reclassify --> Raster to Polygon --> Select By Location (Intersect) --> Delete Features.

This model worked fine when I tested it on one geodatabase's data - but when I try to Iterate Workspace to apply the model to all 73 geodatabases, it cannot figure out where the input feature data is. Each geodatabase has the same data naming conventions within it but with different geodatabase id numbers at the end (ex. M3_drainage_huc_#). So the input features I use for Select by Location look like this ex: %Path%Name%M3_drainage_huc_%HUCNumber%

Any ideas as to why this might be happening and/or ways to work around this issue?

Comment: If you are using inline subsitution shouldn't your expression to a geodatabase be: _%PathName%/M3_drainage_huc_%HUCNumber%.gdb_ ?

Comment: Like Hornbydd mentioned, I would double check your input parameter. Do you have the right slashes in there?

Comment: Thank you both for commenting, I appreciate it! Unfortunately I tried changing it from %Path%/%Name%/... to %PathName%/... and it still didn't work. And under the name paramenters I put in a [-4] to get rid of the .gdb, I also tried both versions of slashes and neither made a difference.